# How to Implement Codeigniter Default pagination with pjax

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, pjax

I want to implement Pjax jquery library with codeigniter Other function just works fine. But when i added it woth pagination and its dont works. when i Click pagination button than its change url but suddenly after its reloading with normal php not ajax..

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

    $FilterData = $this->input->get();

    $config = bootstrapPagination();
    $config['base_url'] = main_url('members');

    $config["total_rows"] = $this->member->browse_search_total($FilterData);
    $config["per_page"] = PER_PAGE;
    $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['members'] = $this->member->browse_search($FilterData, PER_PAGE, $offset);


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] == TRUE)
    {
        $this->load->view('show_members', $data);
    } else
    {
        $this->output->set_template('frontend');
        $this->output->set_title('Members | ' . sitename());
        $this->load->view('show_members', $data);
    }
```

Comment: add your javascript code & the contents of "show_members" view

Comment: Check your developer console.

Comment: From the code you showed, we cannot see the javascript caller part of pjax yet. we only could see the receiver part at this time which the problem is most likely to be existed in the javascript caller part. Maybe something missing like "return false;" in <a href> tag or something like that in the script.

Comment: $config["per_page"] = PER_PAGE; what about this?

Comment: may i know what is the PER_PAGE value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with:

```
$.pjax.defaults.timeout = 3000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try the below config value

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you get `$config["total_rows"]`??

I think it should `$config["total_rows"] = $this->member->browse_search_total($FilterData)->num_rows();`

Comment: Did you mean function browse_search_total return a value that it is total rows?